# core dump file location

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi All,

When I use rosrun to run an executable, I got a segmentation fault. The error message is simply: "Segmentation fault"

I want to debug the core dump file, so I followed this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB

However, I cannot find the core dump file. I am using ROS Indigo with Ubuntu 14.04 and my $ROS_HOME is empty. Can you help to identify this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/226573/core-dump-file-location/) by [Fei](https://answers.ros.org/users/25942/fei/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2016-02-13

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-02-14**:
Have you looked in the `.ros` directory in your home folder?

**Comment by [Fei](https://answers.ros.org/users/25942/fei/) on 2016-03-02**:
I looked at the .ros directory. It's not there. (There is a file called roscore-11311.pid. I believe it is not the core dump file. )

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-03-02**:
You are correct; `roscore-11311.pid` is not the file you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The coredump may be created in `~/.ros`, or it may be created in the directory where you run rosrun, or it may not be generated at all if your system is not configured to generate core dumps (as noted in the tutorial).

If you can reproduce your problem easily and are having trouble obtaining core dumps, you may want to try following the directions in the tutorial for running your node in valgrind or gdb.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2